# Logback file doesn't log info from all classes and all details

Tags: java, logging, logback, lombok

I'm facing a weird situation after removing Log4j and implemented logback via lombok implementation.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class ClassA{

public void executeCode(){
log.info("Hello world");
}

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class ClassB{

public void executeCode(){
log.info("Hello stack members");
}
```

The logback xml file looks like:

```
<configuration scan="true">

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>%boldMagenta(%d{yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss,SSS}) %highlight(%level)-> %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="LOGS_HTML" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/log.html</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
            <pattern>%thread%level%logger%msg</pattern>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ROLLING_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>30GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <file>logs/file.log</file>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="LOGS_HTML"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING_FILE"/>
</root>
```

The file.log is attached to an Allure report, but after run, the file doesn't store the correct execution. Displays some previous runs, and nothing regarding the current one.
Even if I remove the history implementation, the logs are not fully displayed, and those displayed are only from **ClassA**

I need to display all logs during current execution, and nothing more, from all classes available in project.